# How to check address (category city:mtm) and get particular user details from json using typescript in my .ts file?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

***I have give below my json.***

> I need to check the address category type city. but i am able to get
>   the output. I have given below is my json object.

```
[
  {
    "username": "ramu",
    "user_id": "222",
    "profileImage": "ramu.jpg",
    "status": "15",
    "address": [
      {
        "type": "permanent",
        "city": "mtm",
        "pin": "654654",
        "personal": [
          {
            "age": "26",
            "color": "white"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "residential",
        "city": "chennai",
        "pin": "76755624",
        "personal": [
          {
            "age": "26",
            "color": "green"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "username": "raju",
    "user_id": "222",
    "profileImage": "ramu.jpg",
    "status": "15",
    "address": [
      {
        "type": "permanent",
        "city": "mtm",
        "pin": "521001",
        "personal": [
          {
            "age": "26",
            "color": "red"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "residential",
        "city": "chennai",
        "pin": "600024",
        "personal": [
          {
            "age": "26",
            "color": "blue"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Any body help me to check(address category city:mtm) and get particular user details only?**

Comment: @Bharat@Sajeetharan, Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your json even if you filter by city="mtm" it will return all the values from the current json. Assuming you have a different json and you can do as follows.

**DEMO**

```js
var myArray = [
  {
    "username": "ramu",
    "user_id": "222",
    "profileImage": "ramu.jpg",
    "status": "15",
    "address": [
      {
        "type": "permanent",
        "city": "mtm",
        "pin": "654654",
        "personal": [
          {
            "age": "26",
            "color": "white"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "residential",
        "city": "chennai",
        "pin": "76755624",
        "personal": [
          {
            "age": "26",
            "color": "green"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "username": "raju",
    "user_id": "222",
    "profileImage": "ramu.jpg",
    "status": "15",
    "address": [
      {
        "type": "permanent",
        "city": "mtm",
        "pin": "521001",
        "personal": [
          {
            "age": "26",
            "color": "red"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "residential",
        "city": "chennai",
        "pin": "600024",
        "personal": [
          {
            "age": "26",
            "color": "blue"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

let filteredArray = myArray
  .filter((element) => 
    element.address.some((address) => address.city === 'mtm'));
    
console.log(filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class AddressLookUp{
    lookup:{ [index:string]: any};
    userArray:Array<Object>;
    constructor(users:Array<Object>){
        this.userArray = users;
        this.lookup={};
        this._buildLookUp()
    }
     private _buildLookUp():void{
        this.userArray.forEach((currentU:Object,_indexU:number)=>{
            (<any>currentU).address.forEach((currentA:Object,_indexA:number)=>{
                if((<any>currentA).city in this.lookup){
                    this.lookup[(<any>currentA).city].push(_indexU)
                }else{
                    this.lookup[(<any>currentA).city]=new Array(_indexU)
                }
            })
        })
    }
    findByAddress(address:string):Array<Object>{
        return  this.userArray.filter((c,i)=>{
            return i in this.lookup[address]
        }) 
    }
}
```

then use it

```
let lookup = new AddressLookUp(userArray)
console.log(JSON.stringify(lookup.findByAddress("mtm")))
```